# Is it professional to save Users shopping cart in a sessionState for making it persistent using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I want to make a persistent shopping cart for a MVC application, in other words if a user add some products to his/her cart when logged in and leaves the application without making an order or removing the item from his/her cart. I want to let users have their added items in their shopping cart until some certain amount of time lets say one month, ordering or removing the items from his/her cart manually.
Is it a good idea to save their cart in asp.net sessionState? If yes, in which mode,State Server, InProc, Out of Process or SQLServer? 
Regards

Comment: Items in the shopping cart are money not collected. You *don't* want to store them in non-durable storage. Furthermore, they are more than just some state of the web application, they are a customer's potential order that should be accessible from other systems. Storing it in a proper database table is just one option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session state only lasts as long as the user is interacting with your site. Technically a little longer, but once a user navigates away or closes their browser, you should consider the session closed.

**Option A:** 
Use a cookie on the user's computer to store items in their shopping list. Store as little information as possible, maybe just the product SKU and the quantity.

E.g.: To Create the cookie

```
HttpCookie cartCookie = new HttpCookie("TheCart");
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

// Possibly a serialised string of the shopping cart object (ensure no sensitive info though)
cartCookie.Value = shoppingCartData;

// Set when the cookie should expire. 
cartCookie.Expires = now.AddMonths(1);

// Add the cookie too the response
Response.Cookies.Add(cartCookie);
```

To Read the Cookie:

```
HttpCookie cartCookie = new HttpCookie("TheCart");
cartCookie = Request.Cookies["TheCart"];
```

**Option B:** 
If your user is logged in, then persist the cart state in a data store - for example, relational, on disk or in a NoSQL DB.

Comment: Seems a very compelling answer, but would you please tell me what is this sessionState used for?

Comment: Session state is used for keep track of data while users are busy browsing your site. It saves you having to post data between pages and gives a "global" state bag within a user's context. There is also View State, which is embedded in a page and Application State, which is global across all users.  Typically you need to blend these concepts (Session State, Cookies, Application State and View State) to get to an optimal solution. Read up on them to get further insight in to which to use where.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) the suggestions are too helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well I Wouldn't do that.
Let us speak with a scenario:

You logged in with User1 and add a product in cart then logged off.

Surprisingly when you logged in with User2, you will see the same products and same cart which created by User1.

Because Session cookie sytem works with browser based logic. So as long as you are using same browser and unless the cookie is deleted, the cart will remain even if you switch users.